# Meteor: How to log user in using username OR password

Tags: email, meteor, authentication

I have set up a custom login system with my Meteor applications where a created user has a username, email, password, profile (with many other non-important fields there)...

For my login I have the following function:

```
Meteor.loginWithPassword(username, password, function(err) {/* error feedback */});
```

At the moment this works perfectly for logging in with the username but I'd like to be able to log in with email address.

Is there a way to login with username OR email address?

Note that I've added validation on creating a username where the username cannot be an email so I am able to perform an "if isEmail" condition before applying this login function.  Therefore the username and email won't be the same so that factor is not an issue.

Comment: Read the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_loginwithpassword) carefully. `user` can be either a username or an email.

Comment: Thank you, I assumed it was just username.  That simplifies things a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just do something like this

```
Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, function(err) {/* error feedback */});
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I really over-complicated that in my mind.  I assumed the function only took the username into account but it seems to work with username and email.